# Bootstrap glyphicons not showing in production build - Electron + Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, assets, electron, glyphicons

I am building an electron desktop app. I have started with the electron + webpack + vue boilerplate, everything works fine when working in: "npm run dev" mode.

As I make a production build: "npm run build:win32", the app works ok, but the bootstrap glyphicons aren't showing up...:(

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Electron from 'vue-electron'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import App from './App'
import routes from './routes'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

Vue.use(Electron)
Vue.use(Resource)
Vue.use(Router)
Vue.config.debug = true

const router = new Router({
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.js

```
<style>
  @font-face {
      font-family: Lato;
      src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf');
  }

  html, body { height: 100%;margin: 0;}
  body {
    padding-top:70px;
    align-items: center;
    background:
      radial-gradient(
        ellipse at center,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
        rgba(229, 229, 229, .85) 100%
      );
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

  h3 {color: #a4a4a4;}

  .navbar {border-radius: 0px;}
  .menu {background: #dadada!important;overflow: auto;padding:10px 0px 0px 5px;text-align: center;}
  .menu div p {font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;color: #5e5e5e;}
  .menu a {text-decoration: none;float:left;margin-left:20px;}
  .menu a span {display: block;height: 30px;font-size: 20px;}
  .menu a span:hover {color:#36b5dd;}
  .navbar .glyphicon {margin-right: 5px;}

  @media print {
    .menu {display: none;}
  }
</style>

<template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PRB Receptie</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <router-link to="/">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Situatii
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/reception">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Receptie
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/invoice">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Factura
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/clients">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Clienti
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/suppliers">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Furnizori
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link to="/products">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span> Produse
            </router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import store from 'src/vuex/store'

  export default {
    store
  }
</script>
```

dist/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- webpack builds are automatically injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="build.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

webpack.conf.js:

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const pkg = require('./app/package.json')
const settings = require('./config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

let config = {
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  entry: {
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/main.js')
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'imgs/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './app/index.ejs',
      title: settings.name
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/components'),
      'src': path.join(__dirname, 'app/src')
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json', '.css'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, 'app/node_modules')]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax=1',
      scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
    }
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  /**
   * Apply ESLint
   */
  if (settings.eslint) {
    config.module.preLoaders.push(
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }
    )
  }
}

/**
 * Adjust config for production settings
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.devtool = ''

  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}

module.exports = config
```

directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Try to check in dev tools

Comment: did  you manage to find the solution for this?

Comment: I've opened this project, however I can't identify the fix I did. If I remember right it was a minor glitch. Anyway today I don't use Vue / webpack with electron any more, its waayy too over complicated. I highly recommend stock Electron + Polymer. You can set it up really quickly, its robust, fun and much modern as an approach.